# Sylvester-like equation solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, sylvester-equation

I would like to solve a coupled matrix differential equation.

All are $2\times 2$ matrices. Then, I have

\begin{align}
   &\dot{X}=-i (A X - X A)-\eta (B Y - Y B);\\
   &\dot{Y}=-\kappa Y +(B X - X B)
\end{align}
with initial conditions $Y(0)=0$ and $X(0)=\mathcal{I}$ and where all the constants $\kappa, \eta$ are positive.

While this seems like a complicated system to solve, I am interested in some particular limits that I think could make it solvable. The first one is that $\kappa\ll 1$, which when simplifies one of the equations to $\dot{Y}\simeq \eta (B X - X B)$.

The second one is that I am interested in the steady-state solution, that is, the limit when $t\rightarrow \infty$. However, I assumed that I could just take $\dot{X}=0$ and $\dot{Y}=0$ and solve the remaining system. And doing so gives me the wrong result! ($\dot{Y}=0$ would just give me $XB=BX$ and no information about $Y$ which I have to plug in into the 1st equation).

If I don't take the limit of $\kappa\ll 1$ and solve for the steady-state $\dot{X}=\dot{Y}=0$, I then get

\begin{equation}
    -i (AX-XA)=\frac{\eta}{\kappa}(BBX-2BXB-XBB)
\end{equation}

And I am not sure how to solve this equation.

So my question is two-fold:

1. Are my approximations for the steady-state correct? $\dot{X}=\dot{Y}=0$ even if the system is coupled? Why is it not compatible with taking $\kappa\ll 1$?
2. If so, is there a way to solve for $X$? While it reminds me of the Sylvester equation ($AX+XA=C$), it is not true and it is just more complicated.

Comment: Your final steady state form is four linear simultaneous equations, one for each component of X.

Comment: It might make sense to Laplace your original equations too. Then your steady state is the limit as s goes to 0 of $s\check{X}(s)$.

Comment: In the steady state equation, the sign on the $XBB$ term should be positive instead of negative. Also it's not clear if $i$ is a parameter like $\{\eta,\kappa\}$ or if it represents $\sqrt{-{\tt1}\;}\;$

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\vc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$Rewrite the steady-state equation in the following form
$$\eqalign{
C \;=\; DX \;+\; EXF \;+\; XG \\
}$$
then [vectorize](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) it
$$\eqalign{
&\vc{C} \;=\; \LR{I\otimes D \;+\; F^T\otimes E \;+\; G^T\otimes I}\vc{X} \\
&c \;=\; {M}x \\
}$$
This admits a least-squares solution in terms of the pseudoinverse $M^+$
$$\eqalign{
x = M^+c + \LR{I-M^+M}w \\
}$$
where $w$ is an arbitrary vector that can be used to satisfy additional constraints, e.g. symmetry.

If there are no further constraints, then set to it zero.